# MySql for Excel - Imported order error

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm using MySQL for Excel plug-in (1.3.7 version) to import data from my MySQL database into my excel however, excel is only changing the order of the columns (alphabetical order) while the data remain in the same order.

The data rows appear in the order I want, but the header row is wrong!

For example:
If my table is (in MySQL Workbench):

```
id | Name | Date_of_birth
01 | Test1 | 01/01/2001
02 | Test2 | 02/02/2002
```

Excel Tries to import as:

```
Date_of_birth | id | Name     ---> (ALPHABETICAL ORDER)
01 | Test | 01/01/2001
02 | Test2 | 02/02/2002
```

Because the "Name" column is a varchar(100), it does not accept DATE type values below it.
So, I can not import anything into my excel.
The only way that I've found to solve my problem is to put my table in alphabetical order (inside the MYSQL Workbench). But it is very inefficient and I don't want to do that with every table.
Could you help me?
Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please [edit] your question to tell us a bit more about how you are moving data from the DBMS to the spreadsheet program? What tools are you using?  Are you saying the data rows appear in the order you want, but the header row is wrong?

Comment: I'm using MySQL for Excel plug-in. Yes, they are appearing in the order I want but the header row is wrong (It happens when I click the import MySQL Data button or Edit MySQL Data - INSIDE EXCEL).

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying and pasting, try using the "text to columns" button in Excel under the Data tab.

Excel shouldn't be sorting these automatically. Start with a blank worksheet if you can and see if you have the same problem.

Otherwise, please post how you are moving the data from Workbench to Excel. It's likely that is the problem.

Comment: I'm using MySQL for Excel plug-in. I am starting with a blank worksheet, then I click the DATA tab (inside Excel), log into my DataBase remote server and finally when click on the Import MySQL Data or Edit MySQL Data after selecting the table, the error occurs.
"Error copying table data
Vale 'natural_gas' is not suitsble to be converted to a DateTime data type'. It happens because excel is changing the header row order.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. I'm assuming you are using the plugin provided by MySql. If you uncheck the "include headers" checkbox, do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes. The same problem happens.

Comment: Can you convert those dates to text before running the import (or leave them out for now)? This might help you debug the problem.

Comment: It's impossible to convert because the column represents when happened the last update. I would have to delete a very important column. I've tried to delete but the problem happened again because the ID (int type) change it's place too.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help further as I'm not familiar with this plugin. I'd start from scratch and follow a tutorial. Sorting the column names is odd though -- it shouldn't be doing this, certainly not by default.

Comment: Ok J. Burke. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Got stuck on this for a while.  I am surprised I could not find more complaints about this issue.

Deselcting the mysql addin, restarting excel and then reselecting the addin did the trick for me.

Mysql addin
File->options-> addins- manage->com add ins ->go